# Where can I find API reference documentation for springdoc?

Tags: openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

The `springdoc-openapi` java library is a decent library for integrating  Open API 3 with Spring project (alternative for `springfox`).

I was searching for a reference documentation (like [this](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/current/) for `springfox`); I found nothing but the [official website](http://springdoc.org/).
That website explains the usage of library well, but not a complete API reference.

And also there are a couple of decent tutorials out there: [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation), [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/openapi-3-documentation-with-spring-boot), [Piotrminkowski Blog](https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/02/20/microservices-api-documentation-with-springdoc-openapi/). But not any organized API reference documentation.

Is there any good reference?

Answer (score 1):

The reference documentation is available on the springdoc-openapi website:

- https://springdoc.org/

You have also, some video tutorials on YouTube:

- https://youtu.be/utRxyPfFlDw
- https://youtu.be/clN5JOUakVs
- https://youtu.be/Ih7gIHSbVtM

This can be completed by the tutorials you have mentioned above.

If you identify any improvements, please feel free to propose them on the documentation repository:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc.github.io